# Cuál es la diferencia entre estas opciones al invocar un método en JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy comenzando a programar y tengo duda respecto a estas opciones, tienen el mismo nombre pero diferente icono, aparecen al invocar un método.

[image: al invocar me aparece esto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los marcado con el circulo rosado son funciones y los otros son tus propiedades de tu clase

es decir que tu clase uio tienes las propiedades division, multiplicacion, ... y resta

por lo tanto puedes guardar datos en tu propiedad division haciendo uso de tu función(suponiendo que retorna un valor del mismo tipo que la propiedad)

```
uio.division = uio.division(4,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

El de arriba muy probablemente es una variable, el de abajo es una función o método.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso :)

Answer (score 1):

Los de arriba son atributos, color verde con un paquetito, mientras que los de abajo son métodos. Tu atributo division coincide en el nombre con tu método division, sin embargo 
atributo o propiedad y método son cosas distintas. El atributo division que creaste es una variable propia de un objeto creado en esa clase, en donde se guarda un valor, en cambio un método es una instrucción que puede devolver o no un valor, como en el caso de tu método será numero1/numero2 y devuelve un valor. No se si te aclaré un poco tu duda